# creating .csv file in static resource using apex

Tags: singleemailmessage

can i create csv file in static resource using apex coding.In my project,i have written some batch class to insert data into Account Replica object.And i used database.insert.it will skip the failed records.but now i want to make the customers to see the failed records.how can i achieve this...?!urgent requirement,

```
string header = 'Status Code, Message, Fields \n';
        string finalstr = header ;

        List<String> errorlog=new List<String>();
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
            string recordString = '"'+err.getMessage()+'","'+err.getStatusCode()+'","'+err.getFields()+'"\n';
       finalstr = finalstr +recordString;
            errorlog.add(err.getStatusCode()+'Status Code');
            errorlog.add(err.getMessage()+'Message');
            errorlog.add(err.getFields()+'getFields');
        }
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstr);
string csvname= 'Account.csv';
csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new list<string> {'sahityaraghavreddy@gmail.com'};
String subject ='Account CSV';
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
email.setPlainTextBody('Account CSV ');
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAttc});
Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

    }
```

currently iam sending the mail,i know it is not good idea.

Comment: I don't understand. For the moment you send an email with the csv file attached? And now you want to store the file in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Batch class is using

```
 Database.insert(acctList,false);  // allow partial success
```

Then, within the `execute()` method, you can capture the failed accounts in a custom object `Failed_Account__c` and then in the finish() method, read all of the `Failed_Account__c`, construct a CSV, save it in `Document` or `ContentVersion` and send the user an email with a link (where they can download the file).

This strategy has issues however, in that the csv construction could blow up Heap if the # of failures is large for big batch runs. Better to direct user to some VF page that paginates through the failed objects.

There are variations of the above that can be done wherein you use `Database.Stateful` in the batch class and keep the failed records in Heap variables - same heap blow up issues to consider (i.e. # of failures is rare and small)